# Namespaces not working with Codeception (Yii2)

Tags: namespaces, yii2, codeception, yii2-advanced-app, psr-4

Im using Codeception in Yii2 to make acceptance tests and there's no way to access my models because namespaces are not working into these tests.

I have this in my tests/_bootstrap.php

```
 require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
 require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

 $config = require(__DIR__ . '/../console/config/main.php');
 //
 $application = new yii\console\Application( $config );

 ## Added (@vitalik_74)
 Yii::setAlias('@tests', dirname(__DIR__));
```

This in my console/config/main

```
 <?php
 $params = array_merge(
     require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
     require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
 );

 return [
     'id' => 'app-console',
     'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
     'bootstrap' => ['log'],
     'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
     'components' => [
         'log' => [
             'targets' => [
                 [
                     'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                     'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                 ],
             ],
         ],
     ],
     'params' => $params,
 ];

 <?php
 return [
     'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
     'supportEmail' => 'support@example.com',
     'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
 ];
```

And this is one of the wannabe-tests:

```
 <?php namespace tests\acceptance;

 use \AcceptanceTester;
 use backend\models\User; ## I have tried writing it with a / at the beggining

class ListUserCest
{
public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
{

}

public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
}

public function init(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $this->login($I);

    if( User::find()->exists() )
        $I->amGoingTo('List Users having at least one');
    else
        $I->amGoingTo('List Users having any');
}

...
```

I get this error when running the tests:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'backend\models\User' not found in /var/www/project/tests/acceptance/ListUserCest.php on line 21
>   Error: Class 'backend\models\User' not found

Please, help me, I have tried everything I know

**EDIT**

Now (after adding the line recommended by vitalik_74) I can use for example, \Yii methods into the tests but witout the web application configuration, just the console configuration.
I mean, I still can't use \backend\models\User and I can't neither access the Yii::$app->user status (to check if user is logged, for example).

The User model is just a common ActiveRecord model with his tableName, rules, attributeLabels, and some relational methods like getProfile().
It works out of the tests

```
<?php
namespace backend\models;
use common\helpers\MathHelper;
use backend\models\AntropometricData;
use Yii;

class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
...
```

Comment: Please post the backend\models\User class

Comment: Try this. Add in `_bootstrap.php` in end of file this - `Yii::setAlias('@tests', dirname(__DIR__));`

Comment: Please post the backend\models\User class  not the ListUserCest Class

Answer (score 2):

Put the next code to tests/_bootstrap.php:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
require('vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
$config = require('config/web.php');
(new yii\web\Application($config));
```